# How to convert month number to month name in an array

Tags: python

Hello I'm a beginner at using python.

I was trying to convert a specific array "X" (with a size of 1 column and 153 rows) which contain numbers that represent months (eg: "5" "5" "6" etc..)

I was trying to convert it by importing *calendar* but I'm not even sure if what I'm doing is right

code goes like this,

```
import calendar

Y = calendar.month_name[X[:]]
```

where X is an array of 1 column with multiple rows

I know it might be a stupid error but as I've said, I just started to learn python and I would really appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `calendar` and `Calendar` are not the same thing.

Comment: oops that's a typographical error on my part! thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you are getting an error stating: "*list indices must be integers or slices, not list*".
To circumvent this issue, try:

```
import calendar
X=[1,2,3]

def int_to_month(x):
    return calendar.month_name[x]

    
Y = [int_to_month(x) for x in X[:]]
```

This way you can return the `month_name` for each element in your `X` list.

The above script should return: ['January', 'February', 'March']

**EDIT:**

If X is a pandas Series, you may convert it to a list using the `to_list` method:

```
import calendar
import pandas as pd

mycolumn1=[1, 2, 3]
mycolumn2=["foo", "bar", "foo"]

mydata = {"col1":mycolumn1, "col2":mycolumn2}
df=pd.DataFrame(data=mydata)

X = df['col1'].to_list()

def int_to_month(x):
    return calendar.month_name[x]

    
Y = [int_to_month(x) for x in X[:]]
```

Comment: thanks for the help! i still get the "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list" the X is from a dataset I imported. I used `iloc` to locate the specific column and `.values` at the end. is that maybe contributing to the problem? the array I get is *array of int64*. Thanks again!

Comment: So your `X` is not a list but a series from a pandas dataframe, right?

Comment: yup i think so. I tried to convert it to list using `.tolist()` but now I ended up with values that are enclosed in brackets

Comment: It literally does what it says - returns a list of month names.

Comment: I edited my answer to account for pandas series. Please give it a try.

Comment: I just read the edit to your answer. You good sir, are a legend. thank you so much for the help!

Comment: Thanks! Good luck with your project.